selecting indistinguishable balls from an urn
THE QUESTION:
If I have an urn with 8 black balls, 6 white balls, and 10 red balls. 7 balls are drawn without replacement.
a) how many ways can I chose 7 balls
b) what’s the probability of picking 4 black balls.
c) what’s the probability of picking 5 black balls and 2 red balls.
Considering the case where they are distinguishable and indistinguishable.
MY THOUGHTS:
Part a has very different answers, which I believe to be $24 \choose 7$ and $9\choose 2$ -1. But it’s parts b and c that I’m curious about. I think they’d be the same in both cases, but I’d love it if someone could clarify if that’s true and if not why not.
(I got $\frac{1}{24 \choose 7}$ $8 \choose 4$ $16 \choose 3$ and then $\frac{1}{24 \choose 7}$ $8 \choose 5$ $10 \choose 2$)

You used the word indistinguishable in the title, but it's unclear to me how you mean for the sentence fragment "Considering the case where they are distinguishable and undistinguishable" to apply to your multi-part problem statement.  Also worth clarifying: are balls being drawn with replacement or without replacement?

Also, what do you mean by saying that there are two different answers to part (a). In the text book ? By you ? Or what ?

@hardmath I’ve edited the question to include that they are drawn without replacement. I believe the question to be pretty simple in the distinguishable case so I’m particularly interested in where balls of the same colour are indistinguishable.

@trueblueanil it’s an exercise with no solution so I am unsure if I should be expecting different answers (although I have been asked to consider both cases insinuating there could be). I thought my answer was right but evidently I’m struggling to wrap my head around this.

Yes, the probability problems are unaffected by whether balls of the same color are distinguishable.  One intuitive way of seeing this is to first assume that balls of the same color are indistinguishable, and compute the corresponding probability.
Then, attach distinct labels to balls of the same color, to make them distinguishable.  These attached labels can not possibly affect the probability.
I agree with your computations for parts (b) and (c).
In general, with combinatorics oriented probability problems, where you express the probability as $~\dfrac{N}{D},~$ the rule is that you must be consistent in your assumptions for $~N~$ and $~D.~$
In your computations for parts (b) and (c), when you computed $~D = \displaystyle \binom{24}{7},~$ you were (in effect) assuming that balls of the same color are distinguishable.  You also assumed that the order that the balls were selected should be regarded as irrelevant.
In my opinion, these two assumptions were the most convenient assumptions to make.  Then, when you computed $~N~$ for parts (b) and (c), you consistently made the same assumptions.
